# np.busday_count with NaT

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm calculating the diff between two columns of dates with *np.busday_count*, but some values are NaT.

```
in:

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'start_date':[np.datetime64('2021-06-28 21:30:22'),np.datetime64('2021-07-29 21:12:58'), np.datetime64('2021-07-23 17:57:58')], 
    'end_date': [np.datetime64('2021-06-28 21:34:13'),np.datetime64('2021-08-03 11:34:55'), np.datetime64('NaT')]
    })


A = [d.date() for d in df['start_date']]
B = [d.date() for d in df['end_date']]
df['diff'] = np.busday_count(A, B)
```

This is the expected result:

```
  |         start_date |           end_date | diff
0 |2021-06-28 21:30:22 |2021-07-28 21:34:13 |   22
1 |2021-07-29 21:12:58 |2021-08-03 11:34:55 |    3
2 |2021-07-23 17:57:58 |                NaT |  NaN
```

But it returns the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in busday_count
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Whats the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code with for loop `busday_count` is not vectorized

```
l = [np.busday_count(x, y) if x ==x and y == y else pd.NaT for x,y in zip(A,B) ]
Out[632]: [0, 3, NaT]
```